# How do I create a template function for controls of a form?

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, interface, function-templates

This statement will change the position of a form object.

```
lblMessage.Location = new Point(0,0);
```

I would like to write a **generic template function** that can position any form object.

I came up with this, but it is invalid:

```
public void ChangePosition<T>(T form_object)
{
    form_object.Location = new Point(0,0);
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
    ChangePosition(lblMessage);
```

> Error: 'T' does not contain a definition for 'Location' and no
>   extension method 'Location' accepting a first argument of type 'T'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Do I need to mention some kind of interface on the template function? How do I call an extension method on a generic type?

Comment: If I understand your question, you don't need a generic method, a `ChangePosition(Control form_object)` method is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is add `where T : Control` onto the definition of the function. `Control` is the highest point in the hierarchy that defines the `Point Location`.

```
public void ChangePosition<T>(T form_object) where T : Control
{
    form_object.Location = new Point(0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a generic method, you can do it this way:

```
public void ChangePosition(Control form_object)
{
    form_object.Location = new Point(0,0);
}
```

The base class for all controls of your form is `Control` which has `Location` property.

Comment: You even don't need a method and can set the value for `Location` property of all controls. But If you really need a method, I created a method in response to your question to have a method.