# How can I (generically) accept any control and set it's Text property if it has one?

Tags: c#, winforms

As part of my progressbar control, I have added a method to accept any control passed to it which will be used as a method for 'reporting' progress or task status in addition to display on the progressbar itself :

```
public void SetReportObject( object obj ) {

}
```

The problem I am having, is when I go to set the Text value or as some controls have `TextValue`, there is no property available to `obj` and thus generates errors in the IDE preventing this from compiling.

I think, some sort of `typeof` should be implemented, but I am unsure on how to go about this. The object being passed can be any user control.

I am using c# in a WinForms project.

Comment: Why not define method as `SetReportObject(TextBox obj)`? Then you can say `obj.Text = "Whatever"`. Or if you need to maintain `object obj` you can cast it and use it like `((TextBox)obj).Text = "Whatever"`.

Comment: 2 Options off the top of my head.  Use a generic method and pass the type of the control, or cast the object (I'd use the `as` operator and check for null) to a base type that has the `Text` property.

Comment: Problem with those methods, unless I am missing something is I must know the type of the object before hand. I am confident there is a more generic method to do this without restricting the control to specific objects. For example, if I want this control to work with 3rd party controls like DevExpress TextEdit, to cast that type (hard code), then I would have to bundle DevExpress runtimes with the control.  The list is pretty much infinite, so there must be a better solution.  I suggested using `typeof` somehow to dynamically cast or whatever, just don't know how this would be implemented.

Comment: You can always use reflection to check if there is a `Text` property and set it dynamically if so. Not a good option, but would do the trick.

Comment: using reflection is only 1/2 the problem.  still need to do it in a way the type can be figured out. Something like `var foo = new typeof(obj)(); foo.Text = "123";` or  `typeof(obj) foo = new typeof(obj)();`   but even still this would create a new object of that type and not actually reference / call the object that was passed.

Comment: That's not how reflection works, the type is irrelevant if you just check for the existence of a property.

Comment: @SanuelJackson Why you don't just change the input type to `Control`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection to set the property, without needing to know the exact type at compile time. Something like this will do:

```
public void SetReportObject( object obj )
{
    if(obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");

    PropertyInfo textProperty = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Text");
    if(textProperty == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("The control must have a Text property");
    if(!textProperty.CanWrite) throw new InvalidOperationException("The control must have a setteable Text property");

    textProperty.SetValue(obj, "0%", null);
}
```

I think you can take at least `Control` as a base class parameter instead of object, but will vary depending on your usage. I also doubt if this is really a good practice, but certainly do the trick.

Comment: You don't need to use generic method or reflection or trying to type conversion. It's enough to change the input parameter type to `Control` and since all controls have `Text` property, then you can access to `Text` property of input: `public void SetReportObject(Control input) { input.Text= "something"; } `  Here is another similar [Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945723/how-do-i-create-a-template-function-for-controls-of-a-form) The more suitable answer is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35946076/3110834).

Comment: Nice. Havn't tested this, but looks right. If i have any issues (like it's broken code), i will unaccept and explain.  But looks good to me.  Will test it later

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood your problem. If you are handling some type object that is not a Control, I think your api needs the consumer information.

```
public void SetReportObject<T>(T obj, Expression<Func<T, string>> data)
    {
        string yourData = "Something to Notify";
        var exp = data.Body as MemberExpression;
        var pInfo = exp.Member as PropertyInfo;
        pInfo.SetValue(obj, yourData, null);
    }
```

Follow an example that u have to call using a TextBox:

```
SetReportObject<TextBox>(textBox1, x => x.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just accept `Control` as your type, there is a [`Text` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.text(v=vs.110).aspx) on it that all controls will implement.

```
public void SetReportObject( Control obj ) {
   obj.Text = "This is some text";
}
```

However, if you are just using it for reporting progress I would recommend abstracting away the control portion and just use a [`IProgress<int>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

```
public void UpdateProgress(IProgress<int> progress) {
   progress.Report(_currentProgress);
}
```

This has the added benifit of no longer needing to do a `control.Invoke` before you update the text from a non UI thread.

Comment: This is what I also mentioned in the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393786/how-can-i-generically-accept-any-control-and-set-its-text-property-if-it-has#comment60405431_36394427) and linked to the [similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35946076/3110834)

Comment: I recommend removing `IProgress<int>` from the answer, because the existing controls doesn't implement such interface and the user can not implement the interface for all required type just because he need to report a progress. The first edition of answer was really more useful.

Comment: I should clarify.  The progress reporting isn't standard, and would consist of other data indicating that task has been completed, or is starting. So the information pushed to the control will always be in a text format. Next up, solving the problem of the other type of text controls such as ListView / ListBox / etc.  Will have to give this some time and though and several attempts before I post that question, but may be likely I may ask it in the next while. I did try 'Control' before, however it had some issues with certain controls even though they supported the method.

Comment: @SanuelJackson  **1-** Regardless of `IProgress<T>`, I think the Scott's answer is surely a better answer and Using reflection for such requirement is totally misleading. **2-** Would you you mind to clarify *it had some issues with certain controls*? **3-** As another option you can use dynamic. But I think Control is enough **4-** Did you read the linked answer?