# C#:Passing derived classes as one generic parameter

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

I recently started learning more about events/delegates in conjunction with extensions to a class.

I wanted to put what I learned into practice by adding an **extension** method to Windows Form controls called `SetDraggable()`, which in turn uses a `MouseDown` and `MouseMove` events to move the control around.

All works fine, except for the idea that it only applies to a specific control -- in my case, a `Button`.

```
namespace Form_Extensions
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        private static System.Windows.Forms.Button StubButton;
        private static Point MouseDownLocation;
        public static void SetDraggable(this System.Windows.Forms.Button b)
        {
            b.MouseDown += b_MouseDown;
            b.MouseMove += b_MouseMove;
            StubButton = b;
        }

        private static void b_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
            }
        }

        static void b_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                StubButton.Left = e.X + StubButton.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
                StubButton.Top = e.Y + StubButton.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

As can be seen, I need the specific control in order to call the Mouse events -- I cannot access those events from the **parent** class `System.Windows.Forms`.

So my question remains -- is there a concept that allows programmers to **generically pass all derived classes as an argument**. I am basically trying to avoid copy pasting the below code for every single control and would like to generalize it for all classes derived from `System.Windows.Forms`.

As far as I can tell, the main flaw in that idea is the fact that I am *ASSUMING* that all derived classes will have the event I need; however, since a similar thing exists for functions in the form of **Delegates**, I was hoping someone could weigh in for cases involving objects or parameters.

Comment: The parent class isn't `System.Windows.Forms`, that's just the namespace. The parent class is `Control`, and you can certainly use that :) Using a generic method is also possible, but not really necessary. Ideally, you'd also want to avoid those static fields, since it's possible to have multiple concurrent draggables; a closure in the `SetControlDraggable` method will work a lot better. Or just use `sender`, that's really what it's for :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parent class isn't `System.Windows.Forms`, that's just the namespace. The actual parent class is `Control`, and you can certainly use that :) Using a generic method is also possible, but not really necessary.

Ideally, you'd also want to avoid those static fields, since it's possible to have multiple concurrent draggables; a closure in the `SetControlDraggable` method will work a lot better:

```
public static void SetControlDraggable(this Control control)
{
  Point mouseDownLocation = Point.Empty;

  control.MouseDown += (s, e) =>
    {
      if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) mouseDownLocation = e.Location;
    }
  control.MouseUp += (s, e) =>
    {
      if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
      {
        control.Left = e.X + control.Left - mouseDownLocation.X;
        control.Top = e.Y + control.Top - mouseDownLocation.Y;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice idea with the closure. I thought about a way to avoid the static point, but couldn't come up with this elegant solution and then thought that in practice it won't be an issue. But of course this solution is safer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification, and sorry about the mix-up with the namespace. Also appreciate saving me further trouble down the line by getting rid of the static fields!

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for generics here. You can simply use the `Control` base class and your extension will work with all classes derived from `Control`.

```
public static void SetDraggable(this Control c)
{
        c.MouseDown += c_MouseDown;
        c.MouseMove += c_MouseMove;
        control = c;
}
```

And you don't need a static member to keep the control's reference as this is passed as your event handler's `sender` argument:

```
private static void c_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Control control = (Control)sender;
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        control.Left = e.X + control.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
        controlTop = e.Y + control.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

```
  public static class Extensions
{
    private static System.Windows.Forms.Control StubButton;
    private static Point MouseDownLocation;

    public static void SetControlDraggable(this System.Windows.Forms.Control b)
    {
        b.MouseDown += b_MouseDown;
        b.MouseMove += b_MouseMove;
        StubButton = b;
    }

    public static void SetDraggable<T>(this T b)
        where T:System.Windows.Forms.Control
    {
        b.MouseDown += b_MouseDown;
        b.MouseMove += b_MouseMove;
        StubButton = b;
    }

    private static void b_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
        }
    }

    private static void b_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            StubButton.Left = e.X + StubButton.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
            StubButton.Top = e.Y + StubButton.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

About the generic problem, other posts help you to solve the problem. You don't need to make the method to be generic and using `Control` as type of method is enough, also if for any reason you want it to be generic, it's enough to add a where clause that states the type should be derived form `Control` class.

**Extender Provider Components**

For Windows Forms, a good solution for adding such extensions to controls is creating an extender component which brings design time support for you. You can create an extender component and add an `EnableDrag` property to other components then you can set it to true or false to make them draggable.

The property provided by the extender provider actually resides in the extender provider object itself and therefore is not a true property of the component it modifies. But at design time, the property appears in property window for extended controls. Also at run time, you cannot access the property by calling getter and setter methods of extender component.

**Example**

In this example, I've created a `DraggableExtender` extender component. When you drop an instance of this component on your form, all controls will have an additional property named `EnableDrag on draggableExtender1` which you can set it to `true` or `false` at design time. Then the control will be draggable at run-time if you set it to `true`.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
[ProvideProperty("EnableDrag", typeof(Control))]
public class DraggableExtender : Component, IExtenderProvider
{
    private Dictionary<Control, bool> EnableDragValues = 
        new Dictionary<Control, bool>();
    public bool CanExtend(object extendee)
    {
        //You can limit the type of extendee here
        if (extendee is Control)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public bool GetEnableDrag(Control control)
    {
        if (EnableDragValues.ContainsKey(control))
            return EnableDragValues[control];
        return false;
    }
    public void SetEnableDrag(Control control, bool value)
    {
        EnableDragValues[control] = value;
        {
            if (value)
            {
                control.MouseDown += MouseDown;
                control.MouseMove += MouseMove;
                control.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;
            }
            else
            {
                control.MouseDown -= MouseDown;
                control.MouseMove -= MouseMove;
                control.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            }
        }
    }

    Point p1;
    private void MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            p1 = Cursor.Position;
    }
    private void MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            var control = (Control)sender;
            var p = control.Location;
            p.Offset(Cursor.Position.X - p1.X, Cursor.Position.Y - p1.Y);
            control.Location = p;
            p1 = Cursor.Position;
        }
    }
}
```

**Learn More about Extender Provider**

- [Extender Provider Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171836.aspx)
- [IExtenderProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.iextenderprovider.aspx)
- [How to: Implement a HelpLabel Extender Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229066.aspx)

Comment: The generic parameter addressed here as well: [How do I create a template function for controls of a form?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35946076/3110834) but don't miss extender provider option too :)